# Does Cassandra support GIS operations?

Tags: postgis, software-recommendations, apache

We are trying to build out stack on top of geo-spatial data, this means storing more than 10000records per a second. we are using Storm to accelerate receiving the data, but we would like to use some powerful tools like Cassandra to store data. The problem with Cassandra is that it lucks some GIS features. Do you recommend any other Data storage platform to easily query this massive data later ?

Comment: Your question title and body are complementary. Are you asking specifically about Cassandra and a GIS operation which is on-topic here or for an alternative recommendation that may be more on-topic for [softwarerecs.se]?